# WPF button background with two shapes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I want to have a button with 2 background colors, diveded by a part of a elipse. Like this:

[image]

Whats the best way two implement this? I can't find it on the web :(

Answer (score 1):

Put the rectangle and the ellipse in your controltemplate for the button (I suggest you start from the [SimpleButton](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294894%28v=expression.40%29) style in Expression Blend) just like you have in your drawing.

You can then set [ClipToBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx) to `true` on the parent border to make the parts outside the black border hidden.